# How to Turn on/off Wifi using Keyboard shortcut

Tags: syntax, applescript, wifi, shortcut

I tried creating an automator to create a shortcut to Toggle Wifi using keyboard shortcut.

But I get this error message:
Syntax Error
A “{” can’t go after this “)”.

This is the script I ran:

```
set_wifi_on_or_off() {
  networksetup -getairportpower en${n} | grep ": ${1}";
  if test $? -eq 0;
  then
    echo WiFi interface found: en${n};
    eval "networksetup -setairportpower en${n} ${2}"
    return 0;
  fi
  return 1;
}

for n in $(seq 0 10);
do
  if set_wifi_on_or_off "On" "off"; then break; fi;
  if set_wifi_on_or_off "Off" "on"; then break; fi;
done
```

please help

Comment: I don’t see any AppleScript in here; you may get more (and better) responses by replacing "applescript" with the tag for whatever scripting (shell?) language you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

The script you've supplied is written in shell script (more specifically, `bash` or a close relation).  It would be more helpful to post a screen shot of your Automator workflow, given that the script itself seems syntactically fine.  However, you've tagged this question with [applescript](/questions/tagged/applescript), so here's an AppleScript solution:

```
use framework "CoreWLAN"

on WiFiOn:state
        tell my CWWiFiClient's sharedWiFiClient()'s interface()
                if (state as {boolean, anything}) ¬
                        is not in [true, false] ¬
                        then return powerOn()
        
                setPower_error_(state, [])
        end tell
    
        WiFiOn_(null)
end WiFiOn:
```

This handler takes a single parameter, `state`.  If the value passed to it is some equivalent of the boolean values `true` or `false` (these include `true`, `yes`, and `1`; and `false`, `no`, and `0`), then this sets the state of the WiFi to on (`true`) or off (`false`).  Any other value passed to the handler performs a query on the state of the WiFi, returning `true` or `false` to indicate whether the WiFi is currently on (`true`) or off (`false`).

Therefore, to perform a toggle, you can first perform a query, then set the state to the boolean negation of the result:

```
set currentState to WiFi_(null)
WiFi_(not the currentState)
```

This handler and these two lines above need to be pasted into a single **Run AppleScript** action.  There should be no other actions in the workflow.  The workflow should be set to receive *No Input* in *any application*.

Save the workflow as a Quick Action (Service), and assign it the shortcut key combo of your choice.